# "Too many active users" error for access db even though there are less active users

Tags: ms-access, concurrency, vb6, ms-access-2003

In our VB6 application we are using mdb(access database) as backend. But actually mdb file allows 255 concurrent connections. But when my software is opened in about 35 pc together for some user error comes as "Too many active users". But some time this error comes when more than 60 people access the software. When i checked ldb file size was 16 kb which is maximum allowed. Then i checked ldb file content. The ldb file didnt had 255 entries but it had lot of blank entries. In normal it should have continuous entries. But in the error case there where lot of blank entries in between the contents. So i think error is due to these blank entries. But how does blank entries came? How this error can be solved. I am using below connection string

```
DBCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & DBname & ";Jet oledb:database password =" & db_password & ";", "admin", ""
```

Comment: If this is a VB6 program, why have you tagged it C#? There is exactly zero crossover between VB6 (ADO, pre-.NET) and C# (ADO.NET, .NET)...

Comment: But to the question: how many connections are you opening inside the app, and are you *absolutely sure* you are closing them every time?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is not around your connection string or amount of PCs running on the server, but rather the amount of connections that are being opened in code to the database server. You should be re-using the connections that you make to the database for further queries etc.
You probably have code that execute and your connections to the database is never closed and disposed again (maybe when the application is being closed by users) leaving you with a bunch of anonymous connections that have gone dormant. Without some proper research in your code no one would be able to give you a quick answer here.

Comment: Ok.I am using one global connection in my code. Also do u know why there are blank entries in ldb which consumes the space.?

Comment: Are all the entries empty in the ldb? ldb files normally track the computer name and the identity that was used to logon to the db, but the entries are continually overwritten as users access the database and work. It does not give a true reflection of current logged on users. I would suggest using something like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198755/EN-US to see who is logged on. Also I would work in a test environment to ensure that connections are all closed properly after use.

Comment: Not all entries are empty in ldb. There are some entries of user who really using mdb file. But in between these user entries they are lot of blank entries. I think this makes up 255 entries and size of 16 kb. So important is why this blank entries?